# Allow an ArrayList to be used in different classes

Tags: java, arraylist

If I create a class that reads text into an `ArrayList`. How do I access this ArrayList in other classes? What do I declare the ArrayList as in the class?

Then when I want a different class to access it, how do I go about doing that? I have tried making it static but I still don't know how to access it in other classes.

Comment: *Pass* the object (instance) as required. While using a static variable may work, it is messy and I do not encourage the practice. However, without some relevant code, it's hard to provide more insight into good ways to *pass/expose* the relevant object.

Comment: You can create a method getArrayList that will return your arrayList you can then add values to the arraylist as you normally would or you could create a method addToList that takes in a object and adds it to the list.

Answer (score 3):

Declare it as a member e.g.

```
public class A {
   public final List<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<MyObj>();
}
```

and then

```
A a = new A();
a.list; // there you go
```

(note that I've declared it as a `List`, rather than an `ArrayList`. That's an implementation issue, and I could simply choose to expose it as a `Collection`. It's also marked as `final` since I don't want to change it inadvertently. I can revert that decision later if need be).

It is preferable to make it private and access it via an accessor e.g.

```
public class A {
   private final List<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<MyObj>();

   public List<MyObj> getList() {
      return list;
   }
}

A a = new A();
a.getList();
```

although someone external to your class could modify it (!). So you could copy it prior to exposing it, or wrap it using `Collections.unmodifiableList()`.

It is better *still* to hide it completely and ask class `A` to do something for you (which *may* involve that list - that's an implementation detail)

```
public class A {
   private final List<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<MyObj>();

   public void doSomethingForMe() {
      for (MyObj obj : list) {
         // do something...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to add and delete to the arraylist in the other classes as well, would thios still work seeing as it is final?

Comment: Yes. The final refers to the ArrayList, *not* the contents of the ArrayList

Comment: For the first way you did it in that very class would there be a retun type on the method thats writting to it e.g
readtoArrayList(){ }

Comment: And for the second way how would you access it in a different class?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `public` getter for your list in the class containing it. In the class you want to use the list in, create an instance of class containing the list and get the list by calling the getter method.

```
class A {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}


Class B {
    public vois useClassAList() {
        A a = new A();
        List<String> list = a.getList();
        // do what ever you want with the list
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could return the ArrayList from the class using a get method.

```
public class A{

//....

public ArrayList<String> getArray(){
return listToReturn;
}

}
```

therefore you'd only have to call the method and your variable doesnt have to be static:

```
A a = new A();

a.getArray();
```